# Converting/typecasting Int pointer to char pointer, but getting ascii characters?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

So I was going through a tutorial for pointers for C/C++, and the tutor comes to typecasting

he says for C bringing a address from a int pointer to a char pointer can be done like this:

```
int f = 1025;
int *point = &f;
char *point3;
point3 = (char*)point;
```

I do so but I get a smiley face and Diamond acsii image (shown in img link).

So I try using `reinterpret_cast<char*>(point)` since I looked it up thought "maybe this is the C++ equivalent", now it looks like this:

```
int f = 1025;
int *point = &f;
char *point2;
point2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(point);
```

but i still get the two funny acsii characters.

Am i missing something? Not sure how to fix this since i just began on the chapter of pointers.

whole programme

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(){

int f = 1025;
int *point = &f;
cout << sizeof(f) << endl;
cout << "value" << *point << "address" << point << endl;
char *point2;
point2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(point); // using method i found
char *point3;
point3 = (char*)point; // using method given in the tutorial
cout << endl;
cout << "value" << *point2 << "address" << point2 << "   "<< point3 << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[image]

[The Tutorial i was following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTttg85xsbo)

Comment: How are you outputting? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the desired and actual behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i was expecting the value to be 1 (since the tutorial says 1025 as an integer would be 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001,  and that since char is 1 byte only 00000001 would be taken in, thus giving value of 1) and the address to be the same

Comment: That's BS, there's not guarantee that char is 8 bits. And there's no guarantee that you would get the lowest 8 bits ether. And at least you should use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @user3528438, as a matter of fact, OP is guranteed to get the highest byte.

Comment: You are getting exactly what you are asking for. By accessing to your int through a `char*`, you are accessing it's highest byte. Due to little-endian architecture, your highest byte is 1. Now you are printing a char with a value of 1 (**not** '1' - '1' would have a value of 31), and this some weird ASCII art.

Comment: I mean i'm just following what the tutorials telling me, is there a better one for pointers?

Comment: Which tutorial are you talking about?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTttg85xsbo this guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you say

```
point3 = (char*)point
```

You are converting the integer pointer `point` to a character pointer `point3`.  `point` is designed for pointing at whole integers (which of course are multibyte quantities), while `point3` can point at individual bytes.

So now `point3` points at the individual bytes that `point` points to, or in other words, the bytes making up the integer `f`.

But the important point is that *the bytes themselves are not changed in any way*.  By using different kinds of pointers, we can look at the bytes differently, but again, the bytes do not change.

If we say

```
printf("%d\n", *point);
```

we take the integer pointer `point`, fetch the int it points to, and print it.  So of course we see "`1025`".

If we say

```
printf("%02x %02x\n", *point3, *(point3 + 1));
```

we're using `point3` to fetch and print two individual bytes.  We *might* see something like "`01 04`".  Now, what does that mean?
Well, the number 1025 in hexadecimal (base 16) is `0x401`, so we have picked out the two bytes `0x01` and `0x04` which make it up.

(You might wonder why the two bytes look like they're in the "wrong order", and this is because of the common "little endian" representation, which is a story for another day.  But if you were using a "big endian" machine, with 32-bit ints, you would have seen "`00 00`", and you would have been even more confused.)

So why did you get a smiley face and a diamond?  I'm not sure, but those are probably the characters with values 1 and 4 on your machine.  You were probably trying to print them as characters, not as hexadecimal values like I did.

Finally, you might have thought that by "converting an int pointer to a char pointer" you could somehow convert an integer to a string.  But, no, you were not doing anything like that.

Yes, in C, a character pointer (`char *`) is often used to refer to a string.  But this does not mean that by converting something to a `char *`, you are converting it to a string.  (Again, all you're converting is the pointer.)

The bytes which make up the value 1025 are always going to be `0x04` and `0x01`.  The only way to convert them to a decimal string (in C) is to call `printf` and use `%d`, or to call a nonstandard function like `itoa()`.  Or, in C++, you can use `<<`.

Comment: As an addendum, also [look up Type Punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning).

Comment: thanks , i think I'll go read up more before asking this stuff

Answer (score 1):

The reason to see always the value for `char*` is the behavior of the operator<<. This operator consider the `char*` as c-strings, not as addresses.

If you want to print the address cast it to `(void*)`:

```
 cout << (void*) point2;
```

I hope I was clear, and I understood correctly your question.

Comment: thanks, what about values? sorry if im asking too much

Comment: @newbie201 Matteo has it mostly right. what you want to print is the single character pointed at use the dereference operator `*`: `cout << *point3 ;` But do note SergeyA's comments above that the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system will get you.